# Sphinx jinja: different header levels

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to create 'section' and 'subsection' headers using `_templates/autosummary/module.rst`.

The former I found as `{{ name | underline }}`

I don't know how to do this at several levels:

```
{{ name | underline }}

.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}

   {% block functions %}
   {% if functions %}
   {% for item in functions %}
.. <- subsection header here
   .. autofunction:: {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

### Background information

I call this with:

```
.. currentmodule:: depinning_inertia_2024

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: generated

    foo
```